# Get list of objects being used with script run dynamically in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, object

I've class python file like shown below.

```
from easydict import EasyDict as edict
import simplejson

jsonStr = """ { "Item1":{"name": "Please choose from below.", "text": "111.." }, "Item2": {"name": "Please choose from below 2.", "text": "222.." },  "Item3": {"name": "Please choose from below 3.", "text": "333.." } }"""

obj = edict(simplejson.loads(jsonStr))



exec("""
temp1 = obj.Item1.text
obj.Item2.name = "something changed here..."
""")
```

I've dynamic python script injected like above.

In above code, `Item1` and `Item2` objects were being used but `Item3` is not. I need array of objects used for example `["Item1", "Item2"]`. Is there a way to identify which objects were being used with dynamic script being executed like above?

Comment: You can override [`__getattr__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), [`__setattr__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) and [`__delattr__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delattr__).

Comment: Appreciate your response. I've modified my original question which was slight deviation from original one. Please advise how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the id() function to check which objects were created. Every object has a unique id.